# How do I specify custom XML using xmlbeans

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, schema, xmlbeans

I am up to implement a workaround hotfix. We are using an external webservice whose client side was generated using xmlbeans and a big WSDL description.

I need so specify a xml node that is not described in the schema. I know I could go and try to modify the WSDL (which is quite complex) but also want to see if it possible without regenerating the java classes.

So basically what I am looking for is something like this. An XML Object I can put into my tree which just resolves to the given text when serializing to string.

```
XmlObject customNode = XmlObject.Factory.newInstance();
customNode.setXML(
  "<myns:MyNode xmlns:mytypes='http://example.com/myschema' xsi:type='mytypes:DoesNotExistOnClientSideXML'"
);
mySchemaConformantNode.setTheNode(customNode);
```

The Server does understand the type. I am aware that this is not clean. But it is a work around until the correct WSDL is delivered in a new version and in place.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine.  You can create whatever XML structure you like using XmlBeans -- it just won't be schema valid according to the WSDL.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't understand the initial question.  You can use [XmlObject#set](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.6.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html#set%28org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject%29) to replace the contents of the current XmlObject:

```
XmlObject customNode = XmlObject.Factory.parse("xml...")

mySchemaConformantNode.set(customNode);
```